# Issue in m touche capacitive sensing module of PIC

Tags: pic

I am trying to build simple capacitance measurement circuit using m-touch PIC16F707 micro controller.

I have initialized the CPS registers & DAC registers (for internal voltage reference) with below values.
Now the real issue is i am changing the capacitance but the CPS output (i.e. SR latch) digital signal output frequency is constant
could anybody help me whats the potential reason why output digital signal frequency is not getting changed with varying 
capacitance?

note: initialized  DACCON1 to 21 as internal reference voltage  to comparator 1 non inverting input using internal DAC. 
As per PIC user guide for m touche maintaining 2/3rd //Vdd (3.3v) FVR to comparator 1 non inverting input using internal DAC

Appreciate the kind help in advance!!

```
void init_CPSA(char CSchannel)
{
    CPSAON=1;
    CPSARM=1;
    CPSARNG0=1;
    CPSARNG1=1;

    if(CSchannel<16)
        CPSACON1=CSchannel;
    else
        CPSACON1=0;
}

void DAC_init()
{
    DACEN=1;
    DACLPS=1;
    DACOE=1;
    DACPSS1=1;
    DACPSS0=0;
    DACCON1=21;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in your question and not as a picture. Don't forget to use the proper formatting when you do so.

Comment: there is a really good library from microchip in the mcc for mtouch applications which works pretty well.